# Laravel 7.x - how to compare two fields in rule validation?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to create a custom validation for invite field in my register form.

I have a table named invites, like below:

```
invites
-id, 
-description, 
-qty
-used
```

Supose that I have a invite (ID) IVRZ5L with qty = 10 and used = 10. Note that in this case I can't use this invite (IVRZ5L) because all invites was used.

I would like to check if qty is greater than used and avoid that user will be registered if all qty of invite is used.

In my RegisterController I have validator method like this:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
   return Validator::make($data, [                        
      'invite' => ['bail', 'required', Rule::exists('invites', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
         $query->where('qty', '>', 'used');
       })],
      'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
      'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
      'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
   ]);
}
```

This rule isn't working for invite field. What I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
   return Validator::make($data, [                        
      'invite' => [
           'bail', 
           'required',
           Rule::exists('invites', 'id')->where('qty', '>', 'used')
       ],
      'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
      'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
      'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Hello atif, i don't have any problem with password. My problem is with this validation  `'invite' => ['bail', 'required', Rule::exists('invites', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
         $query->where('qty', '>', 'used');
       })],`. Could you help me?

Comment: @Jader I have updated the answer. You don't need a closure you can just do ```Rule::exists('invites', 'id')->where('qty', '>', 'used')``` And it will work. Thanks

Comment: Hi Atif, tks for your answer, but still not working. I tried register an user with invite 1 (has qty, see my data here https://i.imgur.com/vpTlYZ5.png), but validation not allow create register.

Comment: `Rule::exists('invites', 'user_id')->where('qty', '>', 'used')` 
You please try this. You trying to check if user_id exist against this condition.